# LiveData Observers are not being removed after fragment transaction and the onChange method is called when the fragment is added from the backstack

Tags: android, kotlin, android-livedata

I create a click listener in a fragment. That Listener sets a livedata value in the viewmodel. I'm observing that value and when it changes, I put its value in a bundle and pass it in a fragment transaction to the next fragment.

This all works. But when I navagate back to this fragment(with the back button), the observer is called again, and it navigates away.

I have tried:
 - removing the observer.. using extension function as demonstrated in this post 
https://code.luasoftware.com/tutorials/android/android-livedata-observe-once-only-kotlin/

- setting the viewmodel and listener to null after in the observer closure

-tried to reset the value of the livedata string

---

Setting the listener:

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
 super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        val backpackImage = view?.findViewById(R.id.image_backpack) as ImageView
        val  poloImage = view?.findViewById(R.id.polo_image) as ImageView
        val pantsImage = view?.findViewById(R.id.pants_image) as ImageView
        val socksImage = view?.findViewById(R.id.socks_image) as ImageView
        val sweatshirtImage = view?.findViewById(R.id.sweatshirt_image) as ImageView

        categoryOfImageClickListner = View.OnClickListener {
                view->

            when(view.id){

                R.id.image_backpack -> viewModel?.setCategory(Categories.BACKPACKS.storeCategories)

                R.id.polo_image ->viewModel?.setCategory(Categories.POLOS.storeCategories)
                R.id.pants_image ->viewModel?.setCategory(Categories.PANTS.storeCategories)
                R.id.socks_image ->viewModel?.setCategory(Categories.SOCKS.storeCategories)
                R.id.sweatshirt_image ->viewModel?.setCategory(Categories.SWEATSHIRTS.storeCategories)
            }
        }
        backpackImage.setOnClickListener(categoryOfImageClickListner)
        socksImage.setOnClickListener(categoryOfImageClickListner)
        pantsImage.setOnClickListener(categoryOfImageClickListner)
        poloImage.setOnClickListener(categoryOfImageClickListner)
        sweatshirtImage.setOnClickListener(categoryOfImageClickListner)

    }
---------------------
```

the
Observer:

`````````````
  override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {       
...
...

 var categoryObservable :LiveData<String> = viewModel?.getCategoryForNavigation()!!

            categoryObservable.observeOnce(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {

                categoryObservable.removeObservers(this)
                it.let {
                    var args = Bundle()
                    args.putString("CATEGORY", it)
                    val productFrag = ProductListFragment()

                    productFrag.arguments = args


                    val fragmentManger = activity?.let {

                        if (it is FragmentActivity)
                            it.supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                                .replace(R.id.fragment_container, productFrag, "PRODUCTFRAG")
                                .addToBackStack(null)
                                .commit()


                    }


                }


            })

````````````
the
Viewmodel
````````````
class HomeViewModel : ViewModel() {



  var liveDataCategory: MutableLiveData<String> = MutableLiveData()

    fun getCategoryForNavigation(): LiveData<String> =liveDataCategory  // observe this in fragment.. and nav onChange
    fun ResetCategoryForNav()= liveDataCategory.postValue(Categories.SWEATSHIRTS.storeCategories)
    fun setCategory( category: String){
        liveDataCategory.postValue(category)
        Log.d("ONCLICK", "Inside Onclick Viewmodel")
    }
`````````````

Comment: ive also tried to do the back navigation  by deleting the backstack and overiding  onBackPressed ---
    

I couldn't get it to work. I'm also using firebaseAuth.. could that be causing this?